# Apache Netbeans extreme font rendering issues on KDE

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, aur

I've just installed Apache Netbeans in Manjaro, and for some reason the font rendering is completely broken, lacking antialiassing and generally just looking bad.

I've tried adding:

```
--laf Nimbus -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

to my `netbeans.conf` but that hasn't had any effect.

[Example of issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii2Ez.png)

Comment: The link to the screenshot is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've fixed this issue by adding the parameters that you pointed earlier. Just point it on the command line like this:

```
$  netbeans --laf Nimbus -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

If you want desktop integration, you can create a shellscript with that command and point it into the .desktop file for NetBeans at the EXEC field, located at:

```
/usr/share/applications/netbeans.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Apache NetBeans
Comment=Apache NetBeans, The Smarter Way to Code
Exec=/location/to/your/script
Categories=Development;IDE
Icon=netbeans
Terminal=false
```

Although I'm not sure if that is the correct solution, it worked for me.